Is there a way to create a launcher Minecraft with C#?
I have some problem with my C# code, this is my code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using CmlLib.Core;
using CmlLib.Core.Version;
using CmlLib.Core.ProcessBuilder;

namespace MCLauncher
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private MinecraftLauncher _launcher;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            InitLauncher();
        }

        private async void InitLauncher()
        {
            try
            {
                // Set the path to the Minecraft installation directory
                var path = new MinecraftPath("./newmc-launcher");
                _launcher = new MinecraftLauncher(path);

                // Get all available versions asynchronously
                var versions = await _launcher.GetAllVersionsAsync();

                // Update the ComboBox with available versions
                VersionComboBox.ItemsSource = versions.Select(v => v.Id).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any errors that occur
                Console.WriteLine($"Error initializing launcher: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private async void StartMinecraft_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var selectedVersion = VersionComboBox.SelectedItem as string;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedVersion))
                {
                    // Handle case where no version is selected
                    return;
                }

                // Find the selected version
                var version = (await _launcher.GetAllVersionsAsync())
                    .FirstOrDefault(v => v.Id == selectedVersion);

                if (version == null)
                {
                    // Handle case where version is not found
                    Console.WriteLine("Version not found.");
                    return;
                }

                // Build the Minecraft process
                var processBuilder = new MinecraftProcessBuilder(version);

                // Start the Minecraft process
                var result = await processBuilder.StartAsync();

                // Optionally, handle successful start
                Console.WriteLine("Minecraft started successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any errors that occur
                Console.WriteLine($"Error starting Minecraft: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}

And this is the problem:
CS1061: 'IVersionMetadata' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no accessible extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'IVersionMetadata' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
CS1061: 'IVersionMetadata' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no accessible extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'IVersionMetadata' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'context' of 'MinecraftProcessBuilder.MinecraftProcessBuilder(IRulesEvaluator, RulesEvaluatorContext, MLaunchOption)'
CS1061: 'MinecraftProcessBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'StartAsync' and no accessible extension method 'StartAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'MinecraftProcessBuilder' could be found (are MCLauncher you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My question:

Can i use CmlLib for creating launcher Minecraft (an alternative for Game Launcher Creator)?
How I can fix all of that error?

Additional information:

Windows version: 10
.NET version: 8
Additional library: Yes

I try changing this code, but it only show error, it can't fix this.

There are three separate types of errors, all with fairly clear error messages. If you are using an IDE it should also show you exactly where in the code the problem is, and give suggestions to valid properties/methods. Have you checked the documentation of the library you are using? It should tell you how it is intended to be used, and may contain useful examples.

There is 3 error CS1061 and 1 error CS7036
